# How do I check if a const char* begins with a specific string? (C++)

Tags: c++, string, char, constants

I have a const char* variable and I want to check if it begins with a certain string.

For example:

```
string sentence = "Hello, world!";
string other = "Hello";
const char* c = sentence.c_str();

if(/*"c" begins with "other"*/)
{
    //Do something
}
```

How can I do this using the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options that come to mind, one using legacy C calls and another two being more C++ specific.

If you *really* have a `const char *`, it's probably best to use the legacy C one but, since your sample code only creates a `const char *` from a `std::string`, I've offered other solutions as you seem to be working exclusively with strings as the *true* source of the data.

In C++, you can use `string::compare` or `string::find` thus, though the `compare` is likely to be more efficient since it only checks at the start of the string rather than checking everywhere and comparing the return value to zero (the `find` seems more concise so, if you value that and speed is not of the utmost importance, you can use it instead):

```
if (haystack.compare(0, needle.length(), needle) == 0)
if (haystack.find(needle) == 0)
```

Using the legacy C stuff, you can do:

```
if (strncmp (haystack.c_str(), needle.c_str(), needle.length()) == 0)
```

See the following complete program for an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

int main (void) {
    std::string haystack = "xyzzy";
    std::string needle = "xy";
    std::string other = "99";

    if (haystack.compare(0, needle.length(), needle) == 0)
        std::cout << "xy found\n";
    else
        std::cout << "xy not found\n";

    if (haystack.compare(0, other.length(), other) == 0)
        std::cout << "xx found\n";
    else
        std::cout << "xx not found\n";

    return 0;
}
```

For the other options, simply make changes to the `if` statements shown above to match the samples given.

Comment: Surely that's unnecessarily expensive?

Answer (score 6):

To check whether a C string begins with a certain substring, you could use [`strncmp()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncmp).

For C++ strings, there is a `std::string::compare()` overload that accepts offsets and lengths.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the c function `strstr(string1, string2)` which returns a pointer to the first occurence of string2 in string1. If the pointer returned is to string1 then string1 begins with what you wanted to match.

```
const char* str1 = "Hello World";
const char* ptr = strstr(str1, "Hello");
// -----
if(str1 == ptr)
  puts("Found");
```

Keep in mind that you're other variable will need to use it's .c_str() method in the context of the strstr function.